# Boundedness of $f'(x)/x$ implies uniform continuity of $f(x)/x$ on $(1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-continuity

> Let $f:(1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, define $g, h:(1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f'(x)/x$ and $h(x)=f(x)/x$. Suppose $g$ is bounded. Prove that $h$ is uniformly continuous.

I tried by writing $h$ in terms of $f$ and $g$ as: $h(x)=f(x)g(x)/f'(x)$ and then use the fact that $g$ is bounded, meaning $h(x)\le f(x) M/f'(x)$ for some big natural $M$. But then I get stuck.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: As I already said: Please, edit your question to add what you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since f´(x)/x is bounded then exists M such that ...

[image: Proof: Since f´(x)/x is bounded then exists M such that ...]